# Building Remail source for IOS gives error

Tags: ios, command-line, email-client, sasl

I want to build the remail app and i facing compilation issue when i run script file  pull_dependencies, the openssl library compiles fine but the sasl library fails, following are the error messages from terminal :

```
digestmd5.c:1047: error: ‘des_cblock’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

digestmd5.c:1047: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
digestmd5.c:1049: error: ‘des_context_t’ has no member named ‘ivec’
digestmd5.c:1049: error: ‘des_context_t’ has no member named ‘ivec’
digestmd5.c:1049: error: ‘des_context_t’ has no member named ‘ivec’
digestmd5.c:1049: error: ‘des_context_t’ has no member named ‘ivec’
digestmd5.c:1056: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
digestmd5.c:1058: error: ‘des_context_t’ has no member named ‘ivec’
digestmd5.c:1058: error: ‘des_context_t’ has no member named ‘ivec’
digestmd5.c:1058: error: ‘des_context_t’ has no member named ‘ivec’
digestmd5.c:1058: error: ‘des_context_t’ has no member named ‘ivec’

Can any one knw , how to solve this ? i tried things like cleaning and compiling again but it did not work....someone can help me to get this fix.